# 'find() takes no keyword arguments'-error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code in Python which I use to get info about books from a website:

```
publisher = soup.find(attrs = {'itemprop':'publisher'}).getText()
author = soup.find(attrs = {'itemprop':'author'}).getText()
isbn = soup.find(attrs = {'itemprop':'author'}).getText()
```

When I run this, I get a error saying that *find() takes no keyword arguments*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `getText()` or `text` when defining soup you will get the error:

```
   `soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html).getText()` # will give error
```

or:

```
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc).text` # will give error
```

Using `soup.find(attrs = {'itemprop':'publisher'}).getText()` etc.. is completely valid.

As per Jon Clements comment, using `print type(soup)` will clarify.

I imagine you will get `<type 'unicode'>`.

Comment: This seems plausible - might be worth asking OP to clarify by doing a `print type(soup)`

Comment: @JonClements. I added to my answer, hopefully the OP will clarify but there is definitely nothing wrong with using keywords with `find` once  `soup` is not `unicode`.